# Can i change the width of a line chart?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, width, line, charts

Is it possible to change the width of a line series with the chart bundled in .net 4? How would i do it?

Comment: if you are building **web application** i think this link might be useful [Chart ASP.Net 4](http://www.asp.net/aspnet-4/videos/aspnet-4-quick-hit-chart-control) ![alt text](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQllk.jpg)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, you can.

To increase the line width do this:

```
chart.Series["SeriesName"].BorderWidth = 3;
```

I just tested it right now and it works perfectly in a Spline 2D chart.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can

check this link

[Working with MSChart in VB.Net](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/45729dc8-c102-4dc6-9aa7-4f6246763650/mschart-for-vbnet.aspx)

. Setting color and width of Series

For color –setting RBG format
Mschart1.Plot.SeriesCollection(1).DataPoints(1).Brush.FillColor.Set(250,250,)

For width -For that set the Width Property, need to specify Width in Point
MSChart1.Plot.SeriesCollection(1).Pen.Width = 25

Comment: i'm using the bundled chart with .net4. i dont think this is the same chart control.

Comment: You can create a custom XML theme for the .net chart control